# Kohana 3.1.4: Database_Exception [ 2 ]: mysql_connect(): Access denied

Tags: mysql, database, kohana-3

I´m trying to walk through a [tutorial for kohana](http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/04/kohana-tutorial-beginners/)

I have copied the scripts but I getting the following error message:

> ERROR: Database_Exception [ 2 ]: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) ~ MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php [ 67 ]

Could anyone give me some hints to where the problem might lie? I have other projects which use mysql so I know that the password and username are correct.

Comment: Check the credentials you provided to the `/config/database.php` file.

Comment: I´ve checked this many times and still get the same error. I have set the username and password in /config/database.php

Comment: Have you tested those credentials directly with MySQL? Are they *only* failing when used through Kohana?

Comment: Check `var_dump(Kohana::config('database'))` output. Your working config must be at APPPATH/config directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the username in your config/database.php, does the error message change or does it stay the same?

If it changes, then you might have problems with the user permissions on the mysql installation.  If you have PhpMyAdmin, it's simple to fix.  Goto privleges, click the user and enter % for allowable hosts (or if you're paranoid, type just 127.0.0.1 so you can access it only locally).

If it's not, then you haven't setup database.php correctly and we need to see it to correct it.