# Kohana - Database_Exception [ 2 ]: mysql_connect() 2

Tags: mysql, database, kohana, kohana-3.3

I am trying to setup my database config as demonstrated here: http://kowsercse.com/2011/09/04/kohana-tutorial-beginners/

I have cut and pasted the database.php with my mysql credentials. I then get an error which I fixed by renaming the file to Database.php. the next issue is that my credentials don't change no matter what I put in.
The error shows:

> ## Database_Exception [ 2 ]: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'ivanh'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> #### MODPATH/database/classes/Kohana/Database/MySQL.php [ 67 ]

```
62      catch (Exception $e)
63      {
64          // No connection exists
65          $this->_connection = NULL;
66 
67          throw new Database_Exception(':error',
68              array(':error' => $e->getMessage()),
69              $e->getCode());
70      }
71 
72      // \xFF is a better delimiter, but the PHP driver uses underscore
```

So no matter what I insert, username, host and password values do not change.
My code in Database.php is then copied from: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/config
firstly with my own database values then after as is. With no luck.

Other info: I'm creating this on a shared unix host.
[Kohana 3.1.4: Database_Exception [ 2 ]: mysql_connect(): Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483322/kohana-3-1-4-database-exception-2-mysql-connect-access-denied) seems like a similar issue without a resolution.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from the linked question: checking if MySQL works without Kohana & dumping your config?

Answer (score 1):

**Try These Steps:**

**Step 1:**

Go to bootstrap.php
path- kohana\application\bootstrap.php
Un-comment the below line for database access
    'database'   => MODPATH.'database',   // Database access

**Step 2:**
Go to Your config folder, 
create the database.php file if not created, with below codes by giving your MySql credential

Path: kohana\application\config\database.php

Notes: First create a database in your Mysql
If the problem is not solved check your MySql settings too..there may be a error

```
    <?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

return array
(
    'default' =>
 array
    (
        'type'       => 'MySQL',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for MySQL:
             *
             * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
             * string   database     database name
             * string   username     database username
             * string   password     database password
             * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
             * array    variables    system variables as "key => value" pairs
             *
             * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
             */
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'database'   => 'CHANGE YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE',
            'username'   => 'CHANGE YOUR USER NAME HERE',
            'password'   => 'CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',

    ),
    'remote' => array(
        'type'       => 'MySQL',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for PDO:
             *
             * string   dsn         Data Source Name
             * string   username    database username
             * string   password    database password
             * boolean  persistent  use persistent connections?
             */
            'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=CHANGE YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE',
            'username'   => 'CHANGE YOUR USER NAME HERE',
            'password'   => 'CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        /**
         * The following extra options are available for PDO:
         *
         * string   identifier  set the escaping identifier
         */
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the following assumptions:

- You are consequently writing "Database.php" because the file in APPPATH/config containing the code you copied does indeed start with a capital letter.
- You haven't changed the [config reader](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.3/master/application/bootstrap.php#L117).

Database::instance() will [request a config array](https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Database.php#L65) from the Kohana::$config if none is supplied. Config_File::load() will then loop through [all found /config/database.php's](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Config/File/Reader.php#L44) found in APPPATH, enabled modules and SYSPATH.

Unix filesystems are case sensitive, notice the lowercase 'd' Kohana is looking for versus your uppercase 'D'.

If you did name it 'database.php' and not 'Database.php', click on 'Environment' and then 'Included files' on the error page and make sure it is included. If it's not, do some backtracking and try to find out when things stop behaving as they should, followed by why.

Edit: I don't know how I missed the "renamed it to Database.php" part, but that did not fix anything.